# Contractor drilled a 4 inch hole through the center of a load bearing beam

Tags: load-bearing, beam

Contractor drilled a 4 inch hole through the center of a load bearing wood beam. The beam is made up of 3 2x8 sistered together. How can I fix his mistake.

Comment: You don't.  You get the contractor to fix or replace the beam.  Take pictures and start to get ready to send them to your local boards/building inspectors, if contractor does not repair at his expense.

Comment: Not your problem.  You may be able to ask on Law.SE for the best way to sue.

Comment: How does he fix it without replacing the beam?

Comment: Most of the load is taken by the outer surfaces.

Comment: Does he use a 4inch hole saw and and cut three 2x6 plugs . Glue them together and scab on  2x8s on either side?

Comment: The joists are attached to the beam . He cut between the joist through the load bearing wood beam. Would plugs put in along with a 2x8 cut to fit between the joist on either side glued and fastened to the beam be enough

Comment: You need a structural engineer if you are looking for creative options (i.e. not replacing the beam) Plugs and glue are completely deficient to repair a load bearing member, glue is not used for structural purposes and the plug would not return the strength; this is not welding.

Comment: You may want to consider a post underneath until you get it repaired properly. Maybe two posts, one on each side of the hole.

Answer (score 1):

Any structural feature not covered by the framing manual is going to need the blessing of a structural engineer.

If the hole is important it can probably be accommodated in the solution at little cost, the engineers consulting fee will likely outweigh material costs.